# Biblatex does not number references

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex

I'm trying to use Biblatex with the BibTeX backend to do a list of references in a beamer document.

Wherever I \cite something, the number shows up correctly, however in the bibliography all numbers are set to 0. Can someone point towards what I'm doing wrong?

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

In preamble:

```
\bibliography{sources.bib}
```

Then at the very end:

```
\begin{frame}[plain,allowframebreaks]
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

At \cite time it looks like this:

[image: At \cite time it looks like this]

this is what my bibliography looks like:

[image: this is what my bibliography looks like]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue depends on wrong user's settings.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I was setting the beamer template for bibitems.

My file read

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
```

when it should have read

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
```

Comment: hi. I did not define anything in my file, by adding `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` in my preamble solved my problem (almost like your, unlike showing '0' i would get a small icon... Do you know why ?